# Sharing db between Odoo Enterprise and Community Edition

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-9, data-sharing

We're currently using Odoo Community Edition and we planned to try out Enterprise. Just wondering if we can share the same database and fall back to Community Edition if we decided to not to go forward?

Another thing we're exploring is to pay for Enterprise Edition for a number of key employees, and utilizing the Community Edition for the rest of the company with both instance sharing the same database.

Comment: When we are running Odoo server, it will take modules path. Database store records based on module installed. Odoo Enterprise and Community version have different-different functionality and code(api). Odoo Enterprise provide more functionality compare to Community Edition. If we try to do that, might we can face error like of "view, objects, instance, methods not implemented" etc. So I don't think so we can share db between both version.

Comment: @Odedra thanks. As I understand, Odoo Enterprise is only a set of addons, the core should be the same, hence the api should be as well. I'm assuming what ever Enterprise added in the database should not break the Community Edition. I guess the only way to find out for sure is to test it.

Comment: No api is not same. Community Edition doesn't provide *api* for use. I'm sure about that it will break our functionality. Even you may face error like *module not found* You are correct, we need to test it.